# for $|x|+|y|+|z| \leq p$, is there a formula to find the no of integral solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

formula for $|x|+|y|+|z| \leq p$ no of integral solutions?

like formula for $|x|+|y|+|z|= p$ is $4p^2 +2$.

Comment: If you know how many solutions of $|x|+|y|+|z|=n$, then can't you just add that up over all $n$ up to $p$ to get solutions of $|x|+|y|+|z|\le p$?

Comment: |x|+|y|+|z|≤30 do we need to add this for first 30 terms?

Comment: Add over all $n$ from zero up to an including 30. Don't you think so?

Answer (score 2):

If the sum of integers is less than $p$ then you can assume that something added to it will equal $p$. What I mean to say is that introduce another variable $w$ and then find the number of integral solutions to $$|x|+|y|+|z|+|w|=p$$This is just off the top of my head so don't scream at me if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

If we sum $4p^2+2$ for all $p\le n$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{p=0}^n(4p^2+2)
&=\sum_{p=0}^n\left(8\binom{p}{2}+4\binom{p}{1}+2\binom{p}{0}\right)\\
&=8\binom{n+1}{3}+4\binom{n+1}{2}+2\binom{n+1}{1}\\
&=\frac23\left(2n^3+3n^2+4n+3\right)
\end{align}
$$
So, this would be the number of solutions whose sum is less than or equal to $n$.